# Trouble to scrape data from a site using Python

Tags: python, scrape

I am trying to scrape a text from a line using Python. I was able to get the class attribute from the same line but just not the text, tried `.text` and `.get_text()`, and neither of them works.

What am I missing?

Here is my Python script to get the text from the line:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
import datetime
import csv
    
    class toy(object):
    
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    
        browser.get('https://continuumgames.com/product/16-tracer-racer-set/')
        time.sleep(2)
    
        try:
            test = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tab-additional_information"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td').get_attribute('class')
    
        except:
            test = 'NA'
    
        try:
            upcode = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tab-additional_information"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td').text
    
        except:
            upcode = 'NA'
    
    
        print(test)
        print(upcode)
    
    
        browser.close()
```

Here is the page's HTML:

```html
<div class="woocommerce-Tabs-panel woocommerce-Tabs-panel--additional_information panel entry-content wc-tab" id="tab-additional_information" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-title-additional_information" style="display: none;">
 
    <table class="woocommerce-product-attributes shop_attributes">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--weight">
               <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label">Weight</th>
               <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value">2.5 oz</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--dimensions">
               <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label">Dimensions</th>
               <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value">24 × 4 × 2 in</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--attribute_product_upc">
               <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label">UPC</th>
               <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value">605444972168</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
</div>
```

Here is my run:

```
C:\Users\Carre\scrape>python test.py

[WDM] - Current google-chrome version is 83.0.4103
[WDM] - Get LATEST driver version for 83.0.4103
[WDM] - Driver [C:\Users\Carre\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\83.0.4103.39\chromedriver.exe] found in cache

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56807/devtools/browser/03318f43-1d26-44c7-8d90-65233969f03b
woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value
```

Comment: ping the website link

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is probably off. Try using Xpath. Right-click on the tag and then select copy Xpath. Then replace your code with this.

```
upcode = browser.find_element_by_xpath('paste XPath here').text
```

Comment: I have tried with Xpath, and I was able to see the text with Xpath helper, but when running the python script it doesn't print the text.

Comment: without seeing the code where your print the xpath i cant really help you. post enough of your code so i can replicate

Answer (score 0):

I have your solution, this is my usual roundabout way when dealing with inconsistencies on selenium: switch to [beautifulsoup4](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import bs4
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
import datetime
import csv



class toy(object):

    browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

    browser.get('https://continuumgames.com/product/16-tracer-racer-set/')
    time.sleep(2)

    try:
        test = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tab-additional_information"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td').get_attribute('class')

    except:
        test = 'NA'

    try:
        upcode = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tab-additional_information"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td')
        upcode = bs4.BeautifulSoup(upcode.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
        upcode = upcode.text

    except:
        upcode = 'NA'


    print(test)
    print(upcode)


    browser.close()
```

Comment: It works now with bs4, thanks a lot for your tip. I am switching to bs4, just as you said the inconsistencies on selenium, it was not fun to struggle on the code even there was nothing wrong on the logic.